# How to call a default function on instantiating a class object

Tags: scala

I am very new to Scala and have possibly a very naive question but I haven't been able to figure out how to do this. I have the following class/subclass structure, and want to follow a specific API design for the functions defined in it:

```
trait Metrics {
    def t1: Int
}

class Outer extends Metrics {
    val inner1 = new Inner1()
    def defaultOuter: Int = {
        // return some value
    }

    def t1: Int = 1

    class Inner1() extends Metrics {
        val inner2 = new Inner2()

        def defaultInner1: Int = {
            // return some value
        }

        def t1: Int = 2

        class Inner2() extends Metrics {

            def t1: Int = 3

            def defaultInner2: Int = {
                // return some value
            }
        }

    }
}
```

What I want is to provide the trait t1 at each class level, such as the API design is as follows:

```
val outer = new Outer()
outer.t1 // => returns 1
outer.inner1.t1 // => returns 2
outer.inner1.inner2.t1 // => returns 3

// I also want the following:
outer // => to return value of defaultOuter
outer.inner1 // => to return the value of defaultInner1
outer.inner1.inner2 // => to return the value of defaultInner2
// But I can't seem to do that without explicitly calling those default functions which I don't want to.
```

I am not sure if my current class design is conducive for this API structure but please let me know if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to create other instances of the inner classes, just make them `object`s

```
class Outer extends Metrics {
  def t1: Int = 1

  object inner1 extends Metrics {
    def t1: Int = 2

    object inner2 extends Metrics {
      def t1: Int = 3
    }
  }
}
```

This supports the first three operations that you list.

The second set is not possible because the value of `outer` is always going to be the class itself, not a value returned from a method inside `outer`. However you can achieve this:

```
outer() // => to return value of defaultOuter
outer.inner1() // => to return the value of defaultInner1
outer.inner1.inner2() // => to return the value of defaultInner2
```

by defining an `apply` method:

```
class Outer extends Metrics {
  def t1: Int = 1

  def defaultOuter: Int = {
    // return some value
  }
  def apply() = defaultOuter

  object inner1 extends Metrics {
    def t1: Int = 2

    def defaultInner1: Int = {
      // return some value
    }
    def apply() = defaultInner1

    object inner2 extends Metrics {
      def t1: Int = 3

      def defaultInner2: Int = {
        // return some value
      }
      def apply() = defaultInner2
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: One quick follow up, what if I need the first letter of each level reference to not be capitalized, like ```outer.inner1.t1``` and not ```outer.Inner1.t1```, is there any way to do that since object names have to be capitalized?

Comment: Object names are capitalised by convention, but, as in this example, they can be lower case.